# tail->next printing address instead of data circular linked list c++

Tags: c++, list, linked-list

Im trying to tie two ends together in my circular singly linked list. 
In the file name file.txt, containing ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ as text, I was able to
print out the head and tail, A and Z, respectively. however, I'd like Z to point to A
however my output is the address of A ( see below ). What am I doing wrong in addNode()?

```
#include <string.h>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>    // For file input
#include <cassert>    // for assertions
using namespace std;

    FILE *filename = fopen("file.txt", "r"); // Try to open file


struct Node
  {
  char data;
  Node* next;

  } ;

    void addNode( Node * &head, Node * &tail, char input)
      {
      Node *pTemp = new Node;
      pTemp->data = input;

       if( head == NULL)
          {
            head=pTemp;
           tail=pTemp;
               tail->next = head;
          }

      else
          {
          tail->next = pTemp;
                pTemp->next=head;
          }

    tail=pTemp;

      }//end addNode()


    int main()
      {
      assert(filename);
      Node *head=NULL;
       Node *tail=NULL;
      char c =' ';
      int i=0;

      while( fscanf(filename,"%c", &c) != EOF)
        addNode( head,tail, c);



    cout<<endl;
    cout<<"\nHead element is "<<head->data<<endl;
    cout<<"Tail element is "<<tail->data<<endl;
    cout<<"After tail '"<<tail->data<<"' is : "<< tail->next<<endl;

      }
```

Current output is:

```
Head element is A
Tail element is Z
After tail 'Z' is : 0x371168
```

Desired output is:

```
Head element is A
Tail element is Z
After tail 'Z' is : A
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <string.h>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>    // For file input
#include <cassert>    // for assertions
using namespace std;

    FILE *filename = fopen("file.txt", "r"); // Try to open file


struct Node
  {
  char data;
  Node* next;

  } ;

    void addNode( Node * &head, Node * &tail, char input)
      {
      Node *pTemp = new Node;
      pTemp->data = input;

       if( head == NULL)
          {
            head=tail =pTemp;
           tail->next=pTemp;

          }

      else
          {
          pTemp->next = tail->next;
          tail->next=pTemp;
          tail = pTemp;

          }


      }//end addNode()


    int main()
      {
      assert(filename);
      Node *head=NULL;
       Node *tail=NULL;
      char c =' ';
      int i=0;

      while( fscanf(filename,"%c", &c) != EOF)
        addNode( head,tail, c);



    cout<<endl;
    cout<<"\nHead element is "<<head->data<<endl;
    cout<<"Tail element is "<<tail->data<<endl;
    cout<<"After tail '"<<tail->data<<"' is : "<< tail->next->data<<endl;

      }
```

Try this.

I have further improved and removed required code from your addNode.

The reason you want to set "tail->next = pTemp;" is because pTemp is a new memory and because you are making a link list you want previous node (next) pointer to point new memory. Thus it creates a link list.

This way not only you can traverse first and last element. You can traverse the whole link list.

If you miss this statement then you will not be able to traverse. The next variable of previous node will not be connected with the next one.

Example:

```
Node A
[A  | pointer to self] <- head and tail 
Node B
[A  | pointer to B ] <-head
[B  | pointer to A ] <-tail
Node C
[A  | pointer to B ] <-head
[B  | pointer to C ]  
[C  | pointer to A ]   <-tail

Node D
[A  | pointer to B ] <-head
[B  | pointer to C ]  
[C  | pointer to D ]    
[C  | pointer to A ]   <-tail
```

Comment: Thanks this worked fine as well. Do you mind explaning why you set tail->next to pTemp?

Comment: Ok I have updated my post. Please view. YOu made me remember my Data Structure classes .Thank you and God Bless you :)

Answer (score 1):

`tail->next` is just a pointer to the next element. You should still call it's `data` member:

```
cout<<"After tail '"<<tail->data<<"' is : "<< tail->next->data <<endl;
```

Comment: Splendid! i did not know you could further dereference the pointer. Is it possible to do

tail->next->next->data

to traverse into a further nodes' data?

Comment: Yup, sure. You just need to be sure that none of the `next`s are `NULL`, but since it's a cyclic list, that shouldn't happen.